# Firebase reading a number as 'null'

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have an ionic app that I'm working on using firebase realtime database. Essentially, I'm authenticating users using firebase as well as storing user selection input under firebase arrays. I'm still playing around with firebase at the moment and had it working just fine yesterday, however, suddenly today, firebase seems to read my 'id' value as 'null' as per chrome's console.

The code refers to CrudFirebaseDetailPage and the .ts is here:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ViewController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoadingProvider, FirebaseDatabaseProvider } from '../../../../providers/providers';
import { IonicSelectableComponent } from 'ionic-selectable';
import { DiagnosisService } from '../../services';
import { Diagnosis } from '../../types';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-crud-firebase-detail',
    templateUrl: 'crud-firebase-detail.html',
})
export class CrudFirebaseDetailPage {
    private form: FormGroup;
    diagnosisControl: FormControl;
    diagnoses: Diagnosis[];
    action: number;
    data: any = { diagnosis : ''};
    items: any;

    constructor(public nav: NavController, private view: ViewController, private loading: LoadingProvider, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private diagnosisService: DiagnosisService, public params: NavParams, public crud: FirebaseDatabaseProvider) {
        this.action = params.data.action;
        this.data = params.data && params.data.data || this.data;
        this.diagnoses = this.diagnosisService.getDiagnoses();
        this.diagnosisControl = this.formBuilder.control(this.diagnoses[0],
            Validators.required);
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [this.data && this.data.id],
            diagnosis: [this.data && this.diagnosisControl]
        });
    }

    diagnosisChange(event: {
        component: IonicSelectableComponent,
        value: any
    }) {
        console.log(event.value);
    }

    submit() {
        this.loading.present();
        this.crud.save(this.form.value);
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.close();
    }

    close() {
        this.view.dismiss();
    }

}
```

The code also has references to FirebaseDatabaseProvicer under firebase-database.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseDatabaseProvider {

    user: any = {};

  itemsRef:AngularFireList<any>;

    constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase,
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((res) => {
            if (res) this.user = res;
            this.itemsRef = this.afd.list(`users/${this.user.uid}/notes/`);
        })
  }

  get read() {
   return this.itemsRef;
  }

  save(datas) {
    console.log(datas);
    if (datas.id) {
      let tmp = datas.id; 
      console.log(datas);
      this.itemsRef.update(String(tmp), datas);
    }
    else {
      let id = new Date().getTime();
        datas.id = id;
      this.itemsRef.set(String(id),{
        id : id,
        diagnosis : datas.diagnosisControl
      });
    }
  }

  delete(id) {
    this.itemsRef.remove(String(id));
  }

}
```

Essentially, when new data is added to the firebase backend, the array result I'm expecting and I was getting this yesterday was:

```
users
--uid
----notes
------datetimestamp
--------id: datetimestamp
--------diagnosis: {the diagnosis chosen by user}
```

However, today, for some reason, I get the console error:

> Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in
>   property 'users.uid.notes.datetimestamp.diagnosis'

Essentially, I replaced uid with the user id string and datetimestamp with the actually numerical result in all of the above for easier understanding.

The console shows:

{id: null, diagnosis: "Hypothyroidism"}

However, when I expand the value, I see the following:
diagnosis: "Hypothyroidism"
id: 1539049001838

For some reason, the id gets reported as null, even though I'm passing through a resultant numerical value. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. My params weren't playing nicely. I was getting the following array:

```
users
--uid
----notes
------undefined
--------id: datetimestamp
--------diagnosis: {the diagnosis chosen by user}
```

Removed params and added `this.data.id = new Date().getTime();` to CrudFirebaseDetailPage and it seems to work fine.